# Remote Machine not executing program

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Here is what I have so far:

```
$source1="C:\Folder\Files\IPList.txt"
Get-Content $source1 |
Where-Object {-not(gwmi win32_process -ComputerName $_ -filter "name='Program.exe'")} |
Foreach-Object {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {"C:\Program Files\Folder\Folder\Program.exe"}}
```

When I run this in ISE everything comes back as normal and says it has run correctly. However, when I look at my remote machine nothing has been executed. The Process Program.exe is not running and there for the exe should be launched. I am running this from a server to hit about 50 remote machines. Once it goes through all 50, I will loop it and have it do it again, then continue the process in an infinite loop.

What am I missing for the program to start remotely? By the way I am running this script on Server 2008 R2 and it is hitting Windows 7 machines.

***Edit***

I am wondering since I can see the process firing off, is this an issue with Windows 7? I know Microsoft changed things and a service cannot fire off an application in the User space. Do you think this would be part of the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the call (&) operator to the ScriptBlock:

```
$source1="C:\Folder\Files\IPList.txt"
Get-Content $source1 |
Where-Object {-not(gwmi win32_process -ComputerName $_ -filter "name='Program.exe'")} |
Foreach-Object {Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {& "C:\Program Files\Folder\Folder\Program.exe"}}
```

Here's a good article on the various methods available to you: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx

Comment: I read the link, thank you for that. I also tried what you suggested and added &. I can see it trying to launch now but then the process ends and it never launches.

Comment: "I can see it trying to launch"  Can you describe what you're seeing?  Do you see the .exe show up in the list of processes?

Answer (score 0):

In your current syntax, the command your passing is just a string! This is what is happening on the remote end:

```
PS C:\> "C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe"
C:\Program Files\Console2\Console.exe
```

Powershell is echoing your string!

I am going to quote Oliver Lipkau as mentioned here: [Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/ead19612-5e7b-4012-8466-0d650232c7a5/)

*If you need to start a process on a remote computer that keeps running after the script finished, use this function:*

```
Function New-Process ([string]$computername, [string]$name) {   
  ([WMICLASS]"\\$computername\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create($name) 
}
```